# Open application with arguments

Tags: c#

In my app I have a button the user clicks to open a file in an editor. I can get the editor open but the editor opens with no file. I have done this before with the following code and in other cases it works, just for some reason not this case so I'm not sure what Did I make an obvious error I'm not seeing?

I first tried this way:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\App\App.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Multimedia\audio.mp3";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

That opened the editor but did not contain the audio file. I tried this way next with same results:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\App\App.exe", @"C:\Multimedia\audio.mp3");
```

I know there are tons of posts on here and other sites as well but from every one I have been able to find so far, these two methods seemed to work for them. I'm not sure what the problem is. I have verified that the paths are correct and can call this as expected from the command line by copying both paths. Any ideas?

EDIT: I can get this to work correct if I create a file named audio.cmd containing the following

```
"C:\Program Files\App\App.exe" "C:\Multimedia\audio.mp3"
```

And then calling it this way from my application:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Multimedia\go.cmd");
```

The above works but this seems like an extra step that shouldn't be needed to write the strings to a file then call the file.

Comment: Are you sure the application accepts command line arguments?

Comment: he says he can call this from command line so I assume if he types `app "c:\multimedia\audio.mp3"` in `cmd` it works?

Comment: That is correct it does work that way. Edited the original post to include a little more information of a way that does work.

Comment: A suggestion for troubleshooting: Use Process Explorer (from Sysinternals) to see the command line and working directory of the app.exe process and check whether there are any differences depending on whether you called app.exe from the command line or from your application.

Comment: Extra quotes perhaps:  `startInfo.Arguments = @"""C:\Multimedia\audio.mp3""";`?

Comment: I have a feeling that something is not quite right with the editor. Here's what I'd do - create a very simple console app which simply prints "argument=xxxxx" to the screen. Now try launch that console app with your code.

Comment: Extra quotes, knew it had to be something simple I was missing! Thank you so much, works like a charm now.

Comment: @doby48 the argument path mentioned in the question are exactly same what you are using or it contained spaces?